# Formatting a TimeSpan to look like a time zone offset

Tags: c#, timezone, timespan

How can I format a `TimeSpan` object to look like a time zone offset, like this:

```
+0700
```

or

```
-0600
```

I'm using [GetUtcOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get an offset, and its working, but its returning a TimeSpan object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using .Net 4.0 or above, you can use the `ToString` method on timespan with the `hh` and `mm` specifier (not sure if it will display the + and - signs though):

```
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(span.ToString("hhmm"));
```

If not, you can just format the `Hours` and `Minutes` properties along with some conditional formatting to always display the + and - signs:

```
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0:+00;-00}{1:00}", span.Hours, span.Minutes);
```

Reference for TimeSpan format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee372287.aspx

Reference for numeric format strings and conditional formatting of them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: But if `TimeSpan` is negative, it will show result like `-1-30`. Should use `Math.Abs(span.Minutes)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
var timespan = new TimeSpan(-5,0,0); // EST
var offset = String.Format("{0}{1:00}{2:00}",(timespan.Hours >= 0 ? "+" : String.Empty),timespan.Hours,timespan.Minutes);
```

I add the + when the number is non-negative (for negative numbers a - should be output).

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(new DateTimeOffset(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, timeSpan).ToString("zzz"));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTimeOffset(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -timeSpan).ToString("zzz"));
```

outputs:

```
+02:30
-02:30
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this:

```
String.Format("{0:zzz}", ts);
```

Comment: that contains a : between hours and minutes, which could be replaced to fit requirement.

Comment: This outputs both colons and seconds which you'd have to then remove.

Comment: This code gives runtime error: "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'